# Keeping div open after AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an index.php page and an info.php page. The index.php loads the content of info.php into a div.

***Index.php file:***

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <script>
    function loadDoc(){
    $( "#data" ).load( "info.php", function() {
      //console.log( "Load done." );
    });

    };
    $(function(){loadDoc();});
    setInterval (loadDoc, 5000 );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Info.php:***

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box
{
  border:1px solid #101010;
  padding:20px;
}

#back
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$("#openBack").click(function(){
    $("#front").hide();
    $("#back").show();
});

$("#openFront").click(function(){
    $("#back").hide();
    $("#front").show();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="front" class="box">
      front // <a href="#" id="openBack">open back</a>
    </div>
    <div id="back" class="box">
      back // <a href="#" id="openFront">open front</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem**: when I open the div, it closes after a few seconds because the AJAX call replaces the content. How can I prevent this from happening? I thought of making a sort of toggle but I don't understand how to achieve it or if it would solve the problem.

Comment: _it automatically closes after a few seconds because of the AJAX call._ No the ajax request shouldn't closes anything.. Instead if the div is inside `#data` yes since all the DOM inside will be overrided..

Comment: You're correct. How could I solve this?

Comment: The `div` is inside `#data`?? Try to add the relevant HTML/php code please.

Comment: Yes, the div is inside #data on index.php. Everything on info.php is loaded into the #data div. Is there any other code I should post?

Comment: Post the code of the both file index/info

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I updated the question with both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  deferred.promise()

```
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
//pass defferred object in click or your function
$("#openBack").click(function(dfd){
  $("#front").hide();
  //suppose this is your ajax call
  setInterval(function(){
     //if success then resolve with ajax return data
     dfd.resolve("ajax data");
     // if failed then reject
     dfd.reject("if any data need pass");
     //based on hide and show
     $("#back").show();
  }, 3000);
```

});

[See the documentation of promise jquery](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Answer (score 1):

Any content dynamically injected into a page, where not an iframe situation, shouldn't have the outer HTML/HEAD/BODY wrapper, because it may not be handling that correctly...

Every 5 seconds, the interface will be reloaded and wipe out any existing content, replacing it with new content.  Any state will not be preserved.  not sure if that is what you mean; if not, please provide more input and I can help further.